# Minimize Addin hosting server requests

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

For the Outlook Addin deployment, we need a cloud hosted server for JS/HTML.
Caching needs to be enabled by the client is a requirement. Is there a setting for Outlook to cache it for a period of time instead of requesting html/js each time ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such settings in Outlook. But you may instruct the embedded web browser (or just a web browser) by using the [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) HTTP header on files. The field holds directives (instructions) — in both requests and responses — that control caching in browsers and shared caches.